# addEventListeners and React not working as planned

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener

I try to make a timeline that is dynamicaly loaded when scrolling.
Due to this I need the scroll event, combined with React.

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", console.log('scroll'), true);
```

This should console log a scroll every time I scroll, but it just log it once, then nothing

EDIT:

If I use it in my real application now, with this code :

```
callbackFunc = () => {
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (this.isElementInViewport(items[i])) {
                items[i].classList.add("in-view");
            }
        }
    }

componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener("load", function (event) { this.callbackFunc(); }, true);
        window.addEventListener("resize", function (event) { this.callbackFunc(); }, true);
        window.addEventListener("scroll", function (event) { this.callbackFunc(); }, true)
    }
```

It says callbackFunc is not a function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't working because the [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Parameters) expects a function as it's second argument (or an object implementing the EventListner interface) which it will call when the "scroll" occurs. `console.log` is a function, but `console.log("scroll")` isn't a function, its a called function. And so the *value* you are technically putting as the second argument is `undefined` (as `console.log("scroll")` returns `undefined`).

```js
const a = console.log("scroll");
console.log(a); // undefined (the value of your second arugment)
```

So, you need to wrap the `console.log()` in a function, so the function is called, which will then call your `console.log()` method. You can achieve this by using an [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", _ => console.log('scroll'), true);
```

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", _ => console.log('scroll'), true);
```

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
}
```

As per your edit, the arrow function should solve your issue. Currently, the window is calling your event listener function, so `this` is referring to the `window`, not the context of your app. Using an arrow function should fix this (as an arrow function doesn't have it's own `this`).

Comment: It executing it now but I still got a problem. It don't recognise so I suppose it still don't find the function
`window.addEventListener("load", function (event) { this.callbackFunc.bind(this); }, true);`

Comment: @TristanVermeesch does it work if you use an arrow function instead `window.addEventListener("load", e =>  this.callbackFunc(), true);`?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) { console.log('scroll'); }, true);
```

Comment: Why is this working? It definitly solves the problem with why making it a function?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it in reactjs

```
 componentDidMount() lifecycle function
```