# Rock, Paper, Scissors - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Having this issue with trying to use addEventListener where the event I use does not read me clicking the button I have:

```
<input type="button" name="rps_button" id="rps_button" class="box_styled" value="Try Your Luck!">
        <label for="rps_button"></label>
```

```
//The purpose of this JS file is for Rock Paper Scissors.

/*
1- Grab User input & store into variable userAnswer.
2- Get Computer input & store into variable compAnswer.
3- Switch case to compare both answers & give results. 

Loop to check which one is checked
*/


var rps = document.getElementById("rps_button");
var rps_radio = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="rps"]');

var userAnswer = "";
var compAnswer = "";

rps.addEventListener('click', console.log("Clicked!"));

function init(e) {
    uSer(userAnswer);
    console.log(userAnswer);    
}//[End] of Function

function uSer(userAnswer) {
    console.log(rps_radio.value);
    for (var i = 0; i < rps_radio.length; i++) {
        if (rps_radio[i].checked) {
            userAnswer = rps_radio[i]; 
        }//[End] of if
    }//[End] of Loop
    console.log(userAnswer);
    return userAnswer;
}//[End] of Function
```

What am I missing here with this Even issue?

Comment: Where did you call the `init` function? I didn't see it being used anywhere

Comment: Working on steps, trying to get through. Hence when Smokey posted the solution with the Arrow function, I managed to do 

() => init()

Comment: The second argument of `addEventListener()` needs to be a function. `console.log("Clicked!")` is a called function, which returns `undefined`. So, you're actually passing `undefined` as the second argument of addEventListener

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54388142/addeventlisteners-and-react-not-working-as-planned/54388236#54388236) for more details

Comment: Thanks for the information about that, didn't exactly know the difference with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have implemented `addEventListener` incorrectly

This

```
rps.addEventListener('click', console.log("Clicked!"));
```

Should be this

```
rps.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log("Clicked!");
});
```

you could also use a regular function instead of an arrow function

```
rps.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log("Clicked!");
});
```

so basically your event was firing.. but the callback function wasnt implemented correctly, thus why you never got your `console.log()`

below is working example

```js
const rps = document.getElementById("rps_button");
const rps_radio = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="rps"]');

let userAnswer = "";
let compAnswer = "";

rps.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('clicked');
});

function init(e) {
    uSer(userAnswer);
    console.log(userAnswer);    
}

function uSer(userAnswer) {
    console.log(rps_radio.value);
    for (var i = 0; i < rps_radio.length; i++) {
        if (rps_radio[i].checked) {
            userAnswer = rps_radio[i]; 
        }
    }
    console.log(userAnswer);
    return userAnswer;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" name="rps_button" id="rps_button" class="box_styled" value="Try Your Luck!">
<label for="rps_button"></label>
```

Comment: Do you have any reference to the reason behind the arrow function's existence? For the past two hours, between both W3 & MDN, I never seen that & after messing around, I managed to get it.

Note: Currently working on final for class & never have I seen an eventlistener like that before.

Comment: well If you go [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Event_listener_with_anonymous_function) this is an example of using an anonymous function within an event listener

Comment: and if you go [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26/) this will explain the difference between a regular function and an arrow function